# How to remove driver and prevent Windows 10 from updating driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers

How can the 2015 driver be removed from Windows-10?  Driver is circled in red:

[image: Link to screenshot (click here)]

Is there a method to prevent this driver from being updated in the future?

Comment: Is this driver being installed through Windows Update, if so, there is a tool to block driver updates for devices.  How to get rid of that particular driver is easy, install the device, the remove it and choose the option to delete the driver when you do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the old drivers with the inbox tool [pnputil.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800798%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

- run `pnputil -e > C:\drivers.txt`

  [image]
- open the file drivers.txt and look which .inf file is associated with
  the driver you want to remove
- run `pnputil.exe -d oem<NUMBER>.inf`

This removes the driver correctly. If this is too complicated, you can use the tool [DriverStore Explorer [RAPR]](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer)

[image]

Click on `enumerate`, select the 215 driver and click on `Delete Package`.

[Here are the steps to prevent](http://www.howtogeek.com/263851/how-to-prevent-windows-from-automatically-updating-specific-drivers/) that windows installs the driver again.

Comment: Please advise: I rebooted, however, delete fails:   https://s6.postimg.org/z9wbpzcht/snap0092.jpg

Comment: add **-f** to force deletion.

Comment: Successfully deleted:  pnputil.exe -f -d oem2.inf