# Windows 10 frequent BSODs "KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE"

Tags: windows-10, memory, drivers, bsod, kernel

So for the past few weeks I've been experiencing quite frequent BSODs on my Windows 10 machine, this ranges from once every 24-48 hours to multiple times a day, and I can't find any kind of solution to the problem.
The usual error message is "KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE" as reported in the title, and by examining the dumps with windbg it always seems to be some kind of buffer overflow, however the process is not always the same (the last two I checked were Firefox and the GOG Galaxy client).
I also had a few BSODS with the error message related to bad drivers (can't remember it exactly), but I think that was tied to either an old Logitech application or DS4Windows, both of which I've removed from my machine (without fixing the actual problem, it seems).
I have tried checking all my disks, my RAM, full AV scans with both Windows Defender and Malwarebytes and yet I have found no issues and none of these steps have so far resolved my problem.

Has anyone experienced anything similar to this? I have searched for this problem online but there doesn't seem to be a clear solution to it, and Microsoft's help and documentation isn't very useful in this regard either.

If it can help pinpoint the problem I can provide a few of the minidumps I still have to dig through, but I don't think there's much more valuable information in there.
I should also mention that I upgraded my motherboard, CPU and RAM a few months back, but the issue is much more recent and hence I can't say if they are in any way related.
I believe the only thing I haven't tried yet (other than just wiping all my disks and doing a clean install) is updating the BIOS of my motheboard, but again the problem seems to be something recent and I've been using the same bios since I put the motherboard in.

Any help whatsoever would be really appreciated, this problem isn't the end of the world but having my PC restart while doing work/watching a movie/playing a game is really starting to irritate me.

**---------------- EDIT ----------------------**:

My issue, as indicated by the original error code "KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE", came from a misbehaving driver even though by analysing the dumps it seemed like random processes on my machine were responsible.

To pinpoint the culpript I used the Verifier tool built into Windows and selected most of the drivers not signed by Microsoft themselves (I also excluded drivers built by other well known companies or that I had for a long time and didn't give me issues, like Nvidia, AMD, Logitech and Valve). When restarting my machine to let Verifier run I booted directly into a BSOD, this time with a different error code ("DRIVER _VERIFIER_IOMANAGER_VIOLATION") indicating that the issue came from Verifier and one of the drivers this time. By going through the new minidump the misbehaving driver seemed to be ScpVBus.sys, part of ScpToolkit (which was an older version of DS4Windows apparently).

Just to make sure I also run Verifier with only this driver selected and booted again into a BSOD, so I decided to remove the driver assuming this was the cause of my problems. Unfortunately a standard removal procedure didn't seem to work, but I found a guide [here](https://forums.vigem.org/topic/250/scptoolkit-removal-guide) to remove it completely.

A couple of days after removing this driver, I started getting BSODs again. Once again I ran Verifier, this time checking some logitech drivers since I had an issue in the past with a Logitech app, and because by analizyng the stack trace of the dump I could find quite a few references to some HID related components. This did in fact trigger a new wave of BSODs, indicating that one of the drivers was causing some issue, so I removed all of them, uninstalled all Logitech apps from my PC and reinstalled the one I use to control my m+kb from scratch.

This again seemed to solve the problem but after a couple of days I got another BSOD. This time from the stack trace I cannot find mention of any likely culpript, and the process indicated by the dump is firefox.exe.
I noticed a couple of insteresting things in the trace though, and that is:

```
ffffcb82`0220ab18  fffff803`7c87580bUnable to load image \SystemRoot\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvddi.inf_amd64_afaf8d9a55376d3c\nvlddmkm.sys, Win32 error 0n2
 nvlddmkm+0x7f580b
[...]
ffffcb82`0220c0a8  fffff803`6ff10801Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\wd\WdFilter.sys, Win32 error 0n2
 WdFilter+0x40801
```

At this point I believe my only course of action is to somehow completely uninstall the nvidia drivers and reinstall them from scratch, and to somehow fix the missing windows defender driver.
So now my question becomes: How do I do it? If anyone has any idea I'd be grateful for a response, and I can also provide the latest dump if needed (older ones can be found in the comments)

Comment: Read this to see possible causes>>>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x139--kernel-security-check-failure

Comment: hey @Moab, thanks for the link, however I already saw that page and didn't find any useful or actionable information in there. The main culprit from there seems to be a misbehaving driver, but I couldn't find any drivers having issues other than the ones I already mentioned in the OP.
Verifier doesn't seem to help either, it doesn't find any drivers built for older versions of Windows or unsigned ones, and if I ask it to check for all the other drivers the PC will simply reboot into a blue screen (hence no verifier output). 
Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you link a couple of minidumps to start?

Comment: @HelpingHand Sure thing, here are the last three I have: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kSd6AGtYmoC8SZLu_glI1P1tVL91CIDH/view?usp=sharing
Let me know if I can do anything else, I wasn't able to find anything useful in there

Comment: The good news I suppose is it appears pretty consistent. With bugchecks cause by corruption. I would suggest, run verifer.exe. Choose initially the standard settings. Then select driver names from a list. I would probably then sort by the Provider column, and choose up to a maximum of 20 drivers at a time that aren't Microsoft.  I would prioritise new drivers and very old drivers. Certainly any that have been installed recently.  Finish and reboot.  Next time it crashes, can you share the dump from that? Hopefully it will catch a problem. Remember to disable verification of the drivers after.

Comment: @HelpingHand will do asap and let you know what happens, thanks for the help

Comment: @HelpingHand, I've done what you asked and selected most of the drivers on the list not signed by Microsoft. I rebooted into a BSOD (DRIVER
_VERIFIER_IOMANAGER_VIOLATION) which seemed to be caused by ScpVBus.sys, which comes from https://github.com/nefarius/ScpVBus . 
I tried running again verifier with only that driver selected and it does in fact reboot into a blue screen. I'm attaching the two minidumps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NPogBO_YqNmb9rC5CbOT8DmXL3i38wJa/view?usp=sharing .

Comment: @HelpingHand I also tried removing the driver following this procedure https://superuser.com/questions/1103815/how-to-remove-driver-and-prevent-windows-10-from-updating-driver but the driver is still there, is there any way to nuke it from the system? Can I just remove the .sys file from the drivers folder in C?

Comment: So, I managed to remove the misbehaving driver by following this guide: https://forums.vigem.org/topic/250/scptoolkit-removal-guide . Hopefully this fixed the issue, I'm going to try to run verifier on the other drivers I selected the first time and see what happens, will report back if anything happens.

Comment: Just a quick update, this time I didn't reboot into a BSOD so that's already something I guess.

Comment: @HelpingHand the BSODs are back... got a kernel security check failure seemingly caused by Firefox, I tried running verifier again on the drivers I didn't select the first time (mainly the Logitech ones as I had a few issues with a Logitech app) and got three BSODs while Verifier was doing its thing. this time the error code is SYSTEM THREAD EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED, and seems to be caused by either HIDCLASS.sys or WMILIB.SYS (I'm leaning towards HID since Logitech). Any ideas on what I can do? dumps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nawajQecegAPiC6uaaeikrUqyL3booXn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Too many manipulations with verifier and everything else. I suggest, just to be sure of your Windows status, to do [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Not yet solved, I keep having bsods. I've asked for help also [here](https://www.sysnative.com/forums/threads/windows-10-frequent-bsods-%E2%80%9Ckernel_security_check_failure%E2%80%9D.31926/) but so far none of the fixes/tests have produced any useful results. I might go for the repair soon, I was hoping to update to v. 2004 and see if that fixed anything but I am not able to get the update to pop up in windows update.

Comment: I used SCPDriver a few years ago and this happened to me. The only way i got rid of it was to download the media creation tool for windows 10 onto a USB, boot into the USB, delete my entire system and reinstall windows.

Comment: Before the repair-shop, try [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: yeah sorry, by repair I meant the process you suggested :) I'm currently working against a deadline so I don't know when I'll be able to do it but my hope is by this week end.

Comment: @harrymc, just a quick update. The last BSOD I got could have been an outlier, so I am still holding off on the repair install. The machine has been on for ~60 hours without a BSOD, so I decided to run Verifier on all non-microsoft drivers and so far (~12 hours) no issues yet. I might have actually solved the original issue!